# Canny Edge vs Thresholding for contour estimation in Open CV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour, canny-operator

I am using Open CV for an image processing application that involves contour estimation in images. What I would like to know is whether Thresholding the image (like how they have done [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#contours-getting-started)) or using Canny Edge Algorithm ([here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)) yields a better result. Does  this involve algorithmic analysis or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Canny Edge Detection obviously.  It does a whole bunch of things to ensure that only strong edges come out of the result.  Thresholding just takes a look at intensities and sees whether or not each value is smaller or larger and we get "edge" points respectively.  **However**, depending on the complexity of the scene, thresholding and edge detection would yield the same thing.  For example, if you had a clean image with multiple crisp objects that have a clear intensity difference between the foreground and background, then either edge detection or thresholding would work.  If you had a more complex image where the contrast is different in different areas, or if you had multiple objects with different intensities, then thresholding will not give you good results because you would inevitably be including in pixels that don't belong to any proper objects.  This is why edge detection is better, as it's a **local** operator, and thresholding is **global**.  Thresholding applies a set principle to **every single pixel** in the image.  Edge detection decomposes your image into patches and figures out whether something is happening in each of the patches.

---

If you want to take something out of this, the difference between them both is that thresholding is more used for object extraction, while edge detection is a pre-processing step in a processing pipeline, such as contour estimation, object detection and recognition and feature analysis.  Thresholding is a rather quick and dirty way to see whether or not something is happening, or extracting out "active" things while edge detection is more for computer vision related tasks.

---

Instead of explaining how Canny Edge Detection is better, I'm going to refer you to some literature.

- This page from Drexel University was a great thing to get me started: http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/alumni/bGreen/www.pages.drexel.edu/_weg22/can_tut.html
- This page from Computer Vision Online goes into more depth: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/canny.htm

---

Hope this helps!